# Map multiple object properties using LINQ GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to map an object to another object, but I want to group by a key.
I have managed to create the below query, but I need to populate more properties on the object as well as the key and the values.

```
      var results = list.GroupBy(
    c => c.PropertyKey,
    c => c.Value,
    (key, v) => new MyObject {PropertyKey = key, Values = v.ToList()}
  );
```

However, `MyObject` has another property `Color` that I would also like to populate from `list`.

I am trying to do something like:

```
      var results = list.GroupBy(
    c => c.PropertyKey,
    c => c.Color,
    c => c.Value,
    (key, v) => new MyObject {PropertyKey = key, Color = ???, Values = v.ToList()}
  );
```

Can anyone recommend a clean way to do this?

Comment: Can you show how you are going to use `results`. It is not clear *(at least, for me)* what results you expect.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I would be expecting a `List<MyObject>` which would then be passed on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can specify them as anonymous object

```
.GroupBy(c => new { c.PropertyKey, c.Color }, 
         c => c.Value,
        (key, v) => new MyObject { 
                        PropertyKey = key.PropertyKey, 
                        Color = key.Color, 
                        Values = v.ToList() });
```

Comment: I missed your edit. After I made the change everything worked. Thanks so much. This is exactly the clean solution I was looking for